# Visually compare forcasted values (ARIMA model) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm new to time-series analysis. I would like to forecast some values based on an ARIMA model and plot them against the hold out data.

Here's what I have:

```
% Retrieve IBM closing prices
c = yahoo;
IMB_data = fetch(c,'IBM','Close','1-sept-2014','31-dec-2014');
IMB_date = IMB_data(:,1);
IMB_close = IMB_data(:,2); % Contains 85 data points
```

Using `autocorr` and `parcorr`, I deduce that the most appropriate model should be:

```
mdl = arima(1,0,0);
```

Fit the model to the first 60 observations, and reserve the remaining 15 observations to evaluate forecast performance.

```
fit_model = estimate(mdl, IMB_close(1:60));
```

Use the fitted model to forecast a 15-period horizon:

```
[Y, MSE] = forecast(fit_model,15,'Y0',IMB_close(1:60));
```

Visually compare the forecasts to the holdout data:

```
figure
plot(IMB_date, IMB_close,'Color',[.7,.7,.7])
datetick
hold on
plot(61:85,Y,'b');
hold off
```

The problem is that the forecasted values are not being ploted, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So if this is about plotting - can you check if the arima part of the question is relevant?

Comment: Are you sure it is not being plotted? Are IBM_close and Y of the same magnitude? Or is it throwing an error at some point?